# Pine Script Multiple Exits with Conditions from trade

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api

I created **an indicator** that works only for long and shows enters and exits(take-profits) for my position.But during development of **strategy based on indicator** i faced several problems :

1.When i try to setup **two different exits** for strategy - stop-loss and take-profit, **only one of exits works**(take-profit triggers when condition to exit trade is true, condition becomes true when several indicators give signals to exit)

2.If i try to setup stop-loss it most of the time works incorrect - i want to exit from trade by stop-loss by the price of current candle's low,but stop-loss triggers when stop price condition(`ta.lowest(low,20)`) is true for future candle and not sticks for the one on which i entered to trade

[Desired point of stop-loss is marked green and undesired marked red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iw0g.png)

Here is example code for my strategy :

```
// Long enter conditions
emaConditionE = false  
macdConditionE = false    
rsiConditionE = false   
buyConditionE = false   

buyConditionEnter := emaConditionE and 
     macdConditionE and 
     rsiConditionE and 

stopPrice = ta.lowest(low,20)

// Long escape conditions
buyConditionEscape := macdConditionEs and rsiConditionEs 

// Strategy Orders
if (buyConditionEnter and inTradeWindow) 
    qty = [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2XjW.png)
    strategy.entry("ENTER", strategy.long,qty,limit = high,stop = stopPrice)
if(buyConditionEscape and inTradeWindow)
    strategy.exit(id = "TAKE" ,from_entry = "ENTER",limit = low)


strategy.exit(id = "STOP LOSS" ,from_entry = "ENTER",stop = stopPrice)
```

I tried to unite stop-loss with entry `strategy.order("ENTER", strategy.long,qty,limit = high,stop = stopPrice)` but that still didn't work because my stop-loss won't trigger

Answer (score 0):

You need use one `strategy.exit` call like this

```
// Long enter conditions
emaConditionE = false  
macdConditionE = false    
rsiConditionE = false   
buyConditionE = false   

buyConditionEnter := emaConditionE and 
     macdConditionE and 
     rsiConditionE and 

stopPrice = ta.lowest(low,20)

// Long escape conditions
buyConditionEscape := macdConditionEs and rsiConditionEs 

// Strategy Orders
if (buyConditionEnter and inTradeWindow) 
    qty = [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2XjW.png)
    strategy.entry("ENTER", strategy.long,qty,limit = high,stop = stopPrice)

strategy.exit(id = "STOP LOSS" ,from_entry = "ENTER",stop = stopPrice,limit = buyConditionEscape and inTradeWindow ? low : na)
```